# Script not working for second instance of referenced component

Tags: javascript, jquery, instance, repeat

I have a script I'm using to rotate images in an un-ordered list (LI). The script works fine if there is one single instance of the referenced class on the page. However, if I have 2 instances of the rotating component, the second instance does not respond.

I *think* the solution is making the script continue to run until the second rotator gets it, but I'm not sure. I've tried a couple modifications with no luck. The current script is below:

```
function theRotator() {
    //Set the opacity of all images to 0
    $('div.rotator ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});

    // Remove images that only show in main-content
    $('div.rotator ul li.page-only').remove();

    //Get the first image and display it (gets set to full opacity)
    $('div.rotator ul li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

    //Call the rotator function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
    setInterval('rotate()',4000);
}

function rotate() { 
    //Get the first image
    var current = ($('div.rotator ul li.show')?  $('div.rotator ul li.show') : $('div.rotator ul li:first'));

    if ( current.length == 0 ) current = $('div.rotator ul li:first');

    //Get next image, when it reaches the end, rotate it back to the first image
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ? $('div.rotator ul li:first') :current.next()) : $('div.rotator ul li:first'));

    //Un-comment the 3 lines below to get the images in random order

    //var sibs = current.siblings();
    //var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * sibs.length );
    //var next = $( sibs[ rndNum ] );


    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, the show class has higher z-index
    next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('show')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500);

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
    .removeClass('show');

};
setTimeout(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        //Load the slideshow
        theRotator();
        $('div.rotator').fadeIn(500);
        $('div.rotator ul li').fadeIn(500); // tweek for IE
    });
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to replace `:first` in your selectors with `:first-child`. [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) acts like `.first()` and selects only one element, while `:first-child` behaves like its CSS equivalent.

Comment: Good suggestion. However that changed didn't seem to do anything. I think the ":" eliminates first from acting like .first().

Comment: Can you please provide a functional example of your code at http://jsfiddle.net so we can see what it's doing?

Comment: I replaced ALL instances of `:first` with `:first-child` and it seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/xjuah/ -- note also I changed your `setInterval` call to work properly.

Comment: Great thanks! I just noticed another related issue. If the second rotator has more LI's than the first rotator, the first one stops until the second rotator is done with its rotations.  See my updated example, with your changes implemented here: http://jsfiddle.net/trobbins26/5U4Cr/17/

Comment: This will probably require a rethinking of your program's flow. Consider using a separate `setInterval` for each rotator. If you're still having trouble, try to simplify your code as much as possible and post a separate question.

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept your favorite answers to your questions; it encourages others to help you in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was able to find and modify another script to work better for what I was trying to do. A better rotator script is here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ 

Very good tool.